# Repetitive Sequence in Bash

Tags: bash, sequence

I'm stuck in something in my bash script, I have a string that composes of a repetitive sequence of `20`s, e.g. `202020`, there might be more or less `20`s, e.g. `2020` or `2020202020`, I want to create an if condition that if finds any strange number inside, e.g. `30` in `20203020`, gives an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the test:

```
[[ "$var" =~ "^(20)+$" ]]
```

check this:

```
kent$  [[ "202" =~ "^(20)+$" ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"                                                                                                                     
n

kent$  [[ "20203" =~ "^(20)+$" ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"
n

kent$  [[ "20202002" =~ "^(20)+$" ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"                                                                                                                
n

kent$  [[ "20202020" =~ "^(20)+$" ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"                                                                                                                
y
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this example, can you use it?

```
if [ "`echo "202020302020" | sed -e 's/20//g'`"  ]; 
then echo "there is something"; 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended patterns are a tiny bit more compact than regular expressions.

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ $str = +(20) ]]; then
   echo "twenties"
else
   echo "mismatch"
fi
```

At some point, `bash` changed to treat all patterns in `[[...]]` expressions as extended patterns, so the `shopt` command may not be necessary.